Code optimization for attaching a list to another based on time
I have a list which contains date ranges, lets call it shiftRange like below:
start  to  end
9:00am to 10:00 am
10:00am to 11:am
11:00am to 12:00 pm

I have another list which contains employee sign in and sign outs, lets call it applyRecords, which could be overlapping:
    signIn to signOut
E1: 9:10am to 9:30am
E2: 9:20am to 10:10am
E3: 10:10am to 11:00am

Now I use my applyRecords to split the shiftRange to get chunks like:
start  to   end
9:00am to 9:10am
9:10am to 9:20am E1
9:20am to 9:30am E1, E2
9:30am to 10:00am E2
10:00am to 10:10am E2
10:10am to 11:00am E3
11:00am to 12:pm 

This is my code to achieve this, the most optimized I could get, but the issue is I have millions of rows in the ShiftRange and current the execution time is not acceptable, is there a way to optimize it further :
    protected override IEnumerable<TSplit> Join(Query query, IEnumerable<TSplit> shiftRange, IEnumerable<TApply> applyRecords)
    {
        var state = this.GetState(query);
        var applyRecordsCached = applyRecords.ToArray();

        foreach (var split in splitRecords)
        {
            var activeList = new LinkedList<TSplit>();
            activeList.AddLast(split);

            foreach (var apply in applyRecordsCached)
            {
                foreach (var current in activeList.ToList())
                {
                    // Apply split logic and replace nodes in-place
                    activeList.Remove(current);
                    var parts = current.Split(apply); //the Split function returns before, during and after for the event
                    if (parts.Item1 != null) activeList.AddLast(parts.Item1);
                    if (parts.Item2 != null) activeList.AddLast(this.ApplyRecord(apply, parts.Item2, state)); //the ApplyRecord function attaches the apply record to shift range
                    if (parts.Item3 != null) activeList.AddLast(parts.Item3);
                }
            }

            // Emit all remaining parts in order
            foreach (var remainingSplit in activeList)
            {
                yield return remainingSplit;
            }
        }
    }


If you sort your shiftRanges by start time and your applyRecords by sign-in time, the problem becomes a slightly-modified merge, which will be much more efficient than your existing O(n^2) approach. It's unclear to me without more study whether you should sort by start time and duration, or just by start time.

Create a new structure, called an event.  They have a time and a description.
Create events one from each of

shift start
shift end
checkin
checkout

Sort events into time order
Create your chunks from each pair of sorted events, keeping track of who has arrived but not yet left.
Here is the complete C++ code for an application that implements this algorithm.
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct shift
{
    int start;
    int end;
};
struct record
{
    int in;
    int out;
    std::string name;
};
struct event
{
    int time;
    std::string name;

    event(int t)
        : time(t)
    {
    }
    event(int t, const std::string &n)
        : time(t),
          name(n)
    {
    }
};

std::vector<shift> vshift;
std::vector<record> vrecord;
std::vector<event> vevent;

void gen1()
{
    vshift = {
        {900, 1000},
        {1000, 1100},
        {1100, 1200}};

    vrecord = {
        {910, 930, "E1"},
        {920, 1010, "E2"},
        {1010, 1100, "E3"}};
}

void makeEvents(const shift &s)
{
    vevent.emplace_back(s.start);
    vevent.emplace_back(s.end);
}
void makeEvents(const record &r)
{
    vevent.emplace_back(r.in, "in__" + r.name);
    vevent.emplace_back(r.out, "out_" + r.name);
}
void makeEvents()
{
    for (auto &s : vshift)
        makeEvents(s);
    for (auto &r : vrecord)
        makeEvents(r);
}

void makeChunk(
    std::vector<std::string> &vpresent,
    event &s,
    event &e)
{
    // std::cout << "(( " << s.time << " " << s.name << " , " << e.time << " " << e.name << "))\n";

    if (s.time != e.time)
        std::cout << s.time << " to " << e.time << " ";

    // check if anyone arrived or left
    if (!s.name.empty())
    {
        if (s.name.find("in") != -1) {
            // arrival
            vpresent.push_back(s.name.substr(4));
        }
        else
        {
            // departure
            auto it = std::find(
                vpresent.begin(), vpresent.end(),
                s.name.substr(4));
            if (it != vpresent.end())
                vpresent.erase(it);
        }
    }

    if (s.time != e.time)
    {
        for (auto &p : vpresent)
            std::cout << p << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

void makeChunks()
{
    // keep track of who is present
    std::vector<std::string> vpresent;

    // create 'chunks' from each pair of events
    for (int k = 0; k < vevent.size() - 1; k++)
        makeChunk(vpresent, vevent[k], vevent[k + 1]);
}

main()
{
    // generate example problem
    gen1();

    // make all the events
    makeEvents();

    // sort events by time
    std::sort(
        vevent.begin(), vevent.end(),
        [](const event &a, const event &b)
        {
            return a.time < b.time;
        });

    // make and display the 'chunks'
    makeChunks();

    return 0;
}

The output is:
900 to 910 
910 to 920 E1
920 to 930 E1 E2
930 to 1000 E2
1000 to 1010 E2
1010 to 1100 E3
1100 to 1200

You should be able to port the code to C# without too much difficulty.  It will likely run somewhat slower in c#, of course.
The VSCODE project to build this is in the github repo https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79292219
